# Is there a way to reset SQL Server 2008 Express to default configuration and data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to reset a SQL Server Express 2008 to it's initial configuration? Maybe re-creating the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not a way to reset SQL Server Express to the default configuration and data.

Your best bet would be to uninstall Express and reinstall it.

Comment: Brent is right, and if you tried to manually compare your current instance to a "default" configuration, it would take a lot more time than it will to just reinstall.

Answer (score -1):

Without providing more information on what you have changed its hard to answer your question properly.

You may want think about joining a SQL community to help you with your learning.

I use [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/) and have found the forums and scripts to be a valuable resource when needing to extract information during my daily DBA tasks

Disclaimer: I am a member of the site but not affiliated in any other way.

Comment: I've changed many things, like protocols available and other bits. I'm most worried about those I don't remember I change.

Comment: Why vote down? He has asked several questions on SQL server and this post was about joining another community SQL specific.